# React Native border radius rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When you add a border radius to a border in CSS the border will gradually decline in width around the border radius, as you can see in this example:

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

I am trying to do the same within React Native, however React Native seems to cut off the last bit:

[image: React native example]

As you can see it doesn't taper off the border along the radius.

What would be the best approach to get the border to taper off like it does in web engines?

Comment: For IOS, you just need to add `overflow: hidden` to your styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faced the same problem and couldn't find a solution with borderRadius styles. Solved by using two Views with different height. But not sure whether is it a good approach. Check [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@dinithminura/Ym9yZG) for a working sample.

```
view1:{        
    width:200,
    height:100,
    backgroundColor:'red',
    borderRadius:10,    
    alignItems:'center'
  },

view2:{
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width:200,
    height:95,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    borderBottomEndRadius:10,
    borderBottomStartRadius:10
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I will keep this one in mind whilst waiting for additional solutions. I want to use this effect for a great variety of elements, which would result in quite some additional coding and possibly element specific adjustments which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Sure @MelvinKoopmans , Others may have better solutions. If we can have specific adjustments in styling it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your border clips because you've just set a `bottom` border. Try also applying a `left` and `right` border with the same width and color, and it will properly work.

Natural intuition would make you think that the corners should be part of the "top" of the view, but they are actually the sides.